# PhotoView zoom is not smooth

Tags: android, android-glide, android-photoview

I use `PhotoView` in my project and use `Glide` to load image into it.

ViewPager + `PhotoView` load local image.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imagePaths.get(position))
            .skipMemoryCache(false)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(photoView);
```

But the zoom in/out operation is not smooth at all.

Who can tell me why ??

Comment: What is `PhotoView`?

Comment: @Henry An open-source library [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Comment: @L.Meng did you get any solution for this...facing same issue...zoom action is jerking and gives a bad user experience